# Ubuntu 14.04 lts 64bit boot problem

Tags: 14.04, boot, virtualbox, 64-bit, busybox

**Hello Ladies and Gentleman,**

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu 14.04 lts, i installed it 3 months ago and it was working fine until yesterday, i was dealing with Windows 8 in virtualbox. After that i log out from my Ubuntu root session to switch to another one, when suddenly Ubuntu stuck in a blinking cursor, so i have rebooted my PC and it prompts me with grub options, i tried all options which provides me all the time this output:

```
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/53dc799e-7378-49bd-a0e7-93370d11e5551 on /root failed: invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
No init found - Try passing init=bootarg

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu 1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(initramfs) _
```

**This is my "uname -a" output:**

`Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**Some additional infos maybe helpful:**

- *My external hard drive was plugged in when i rebooted my PC.*
- *I have a Sony Vaio Intel Core i3 / 3GB RAM / 320 GB TOSHIBA MK3265GSX (GJ002H) Hard drive.*
- *I have from a long time (when i was using Windows 7) a Smart internal harddisk Failure Predicted message when i start my PC but i use it normally.*
- *When i try to open my harddrive with Ubuntu LiveCD boot it show this in a box:*

> #### **Error mounting filesystem**
>
> Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ubuntu/53dc799e-7378-49bd a0e7-93370d1e5551: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sda1" "/media/ubuntu/53dc799e-7378-49bd-a0e7-93370d1e5551"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
>
> ```
>   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>   dmesg | tail  or so
> ```
>
> (udisks-error-quark, 0)####
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   If someone could help me, it would be great. (Sorry for my bad English !)

**NEW EDIT:**
I enjoy your opinion @JavierRivera, maybe i have to try boot-repair [link](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/boot-repair) to retrieve my data.
by the way this is last part of **`dmesg`** output which i see is related to my problem:

`[  445.456676] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  445.456681] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[  445.508901] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[  445.508936] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[  445.508942] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]

[  445.508945] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  445.508949] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]

[  445.508952] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[  445.508957] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[  445.508959]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[  445.508969]         12 44 97 99 
[  445.508973] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]

[  445.508976] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  445.508979] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[  445.508981] Read(10): 28 00 12 44 97 98 00 00 08 00
[  445.508990] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 306485145
[  445.509016] ata1: EH complete
[  445.509052] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 4595
[  445.509067] JBD2: recovery failed
[  445.509071] EXT4-fs (sda1): error loading journal`

I have to retrieve my data, so an attention from your part would be Seriously Geekly Great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like S.M.A.R.T. was right at the end and your hard disk failed to me.

All the messages that you are receiving, both at boot and with the live CD are related to problems reading the disk.

You can type:

```
dmesg
```

on the command line to get additional errors and more information and you can also run the Disks tools from the live cd to get SMART data out of the disk. But if I were you I'd replace my hard disk as soon as possible.

Comment: I enjoy your opinion @JavierRivera, i added a part of **`dmesg`** output above.

Comment: There are bad sector and no place to reallocate them, and some read errors. You should change the disk ASAP, if there is important information in it, stop using it as it will probably get worse making data recovery harder.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, boot repair [link](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/boot-repair) fixes my problem, now i can log in but the ***GNU Grub*** menu prompts even after a reboot, also i noticed when i open Terminal it displays `$` only unlike `root@user:~$` and that Ubuntu is slow to boot and as well when opening applications !

Comment: @JavierRivera now i can backup my data and change my Hard Drive !